# DropDownListFor not binding in EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can not get a DropDownListFor to bind to my model.  The DisplayOrder returns null and VarietyFamilyID is always 0.   I have an unknown number of objects to edit, so I am trying to use a EditorTemplate.

EditorTemplate view

```
@model Wysocki_Variety_Management.Models.Image

<div>
   @Html.HiddenFor(i=>i.ImageStreamID)
   @Model.helperString
   @Html.DropDownListFor(i=>i.DisplayOrder, new SelectList(ViewBag.DisplayOptions, "Key", "Value"))
   @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.VarietyFamilyID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Variety, "VarietyFamilyID", "Name"))
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Try Me",
                        "UpdateImage",
                        "Images",
                         new { s = Model.ImageStreamID, dislplayOrder = Model.DisplayOrder, familyID = Model.VarietyFamilyID },
                         new AjaxOptions {})
</div>
```

View to render template

```
@model List<Wysocki_Variety_Management.Models.Image>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateImage", "Images"))

{    
   <div>
      @Html.EditorForModel()
   </div>
}
```

Controller Action Signature

```
 public ActionResult UpdateImage(Guid s, int displayOrder,int familyID)
```

EDIT

Not sure about the down vote or the comment.  When I use the EditorTemplate and @Html.EditorForModel I get multiple inputs for each member of the Model.

```
<form action="/Images/UpdateImage" method="post">   <div>
      <div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Guid field is required." name="[0].ImageStreamID" type="hidden" value="e48aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008" />

   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[0].DisplayOrder"><option value="312">Tuber</option>
<option value="313">Plant</option>
<option value="314">Marketing</option>
</select>
   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[0].VarietyFamilyID"><option value="0">Fianna</option>
<option value="0">Linzer Delikatesse</option>
<option value="3">Markies</option>
<option value="0">Provento</option>
<option value="5">Roko</option>
<option value="6">75-11-15 Sprint</option>
<option value="7">Alegria</option>

</select>
   <a data-ajax="true" href="/Images/UpdateImage?s=e48aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008&amp;dislplayOrder=0&amp;familyID=0">Try Me</a>
</div><div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Guid field is required." name="[1].ImageStreamID" type="hidden" value="e58aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008" />

   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[1].DisplayOrder"><option value="312">Tuber</option>
<option value="313">Plant</option>
<option value="314">Marketing</option>
</select>
   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[1].VarietyFamilyID"><option value="0">Fianna</option>
<option value="0">Linzer Delikatesse</option>
<option value="3">Markies</option>
<option value="0">Provento</option>
<option value="5">Roko</option>
<option value="6">75-11-15 Sprint</option>
<option value="7">Alegria</option>

</select>
   <a data-ajax="true" href="/Images/UpdateImage?s=e58aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008&amp;dislplayOrder=0&amp;familyID=0">Try Me</a>
</div><div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Guid field is required." name="[2].ImageStreamID" type="hidden" value="e68aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008" />

   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[2].DisplayOrder"><option value="312">Tuber</option>
<option value="313">Plant</option>
<option value="314">Marketing</option>
</select>
   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[2].VarietyFamilyID"><option value="0">Fianna</option>
<option value="0">Linzer Delikatesse</option>
<option value="3">Markies</option>
<option value="0">Provento</option>
<option value="5">Roko</option>
<option value="6">75-11-15 Sprint</option>
<option value="7">Alegria</option><option value="331">A02507-2LB</option>

</select>
   <a data-ajax="true" href="/Images/UpdateImage?s=e68aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008&amp;dislplayOrder=0&amp;familyID=0">Try Me</a>
</div><div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Guid field is required." name="[3].ImageStreamID" type="hidden" value="e78aab34-0fe6-e511-8ebf-005056c00008" />

   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[3].DisplayOrder"><option value="312">Tuber</option>
<option value="313">Plant</option>
<option value="314">Marketing</option>
</select>
   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[3].VarietyFamilyID"><option value="0">Fianna</option>
<option value="0">Linzer Delikatesse</option>
<option value="3">Markies</option>
<option value="0">Provento</option>
<option value="5">Roko</option>
<option value="6">75-11-15 Sprint</option>
<option value="7">Alegria</option>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I have an unknown number of objects to edit_? The view you have shown only renders one object unless the model is `IEnumerable<Image>` in which case the model in your POST method must also be `IEnumerable<Image>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model in your view is `IEnumerable<Image>` so in order to bind when you submit the form, the method must be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateImage(IEnumerable<Image> model)
```

and model will contain 3 correctly bound `Image` objects.

A form posts back name/value pairs based on the `name` and `value` attributes of successful form controls and the `DefaultModelBinder` matches those with your parameters and model properties. Currently the parameters in your method are `Guid s, int displayOrder, int familyID` and the only way that values could be bound to those parameters is if your form contained controls with `name="s"`, `name="displayOrder"` and `name="familyID"`.

Note that you use of `@Ajax.ActionLink()` in the `EditorTemplate` would only ever post back the initial values of the model. If you want to post the values of the form controls, then you need to submit the form.

Comment: See updated answer. Reading you question again, I can only assume that your under the impression that your `Ajax.ActionLink()` would send the values of the form controls to your method - it wont.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I will figure all this out someday.